# Error when attempting to save image data on Mac/iOS with Haxe

Tags: ios, macos, haxe

I'm creating a set of Haxe functions that saves text and images to a file. These functions work just fine on Windows and Android; however, a tester has informed me that attempting to save an image produces this error on iOS and Mac:

```
ERROR: Failure type not string @ ./File.cpp:123
```

Here's the code for the two functions.

```
public static function savePNG(path:String, image:BitmapData, ?whenDone:Bool->Void):Void {
    if (path.substr(path.length - 4).toLowerCase() != ".png") { path += ".png"; }

    // Flash: Not possible to save; error out
    #if flash
    trace("ERROR: File IO cannot be accessed on Flash.");
    if (whenDone != null)
        whenDone(false);
    #elseif js
    trace("ERROR: File IO cannot be accessed on HTML5.");
    if (whenDone != null)
        whenDone(false);

    // Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, and Android: Use the "saveText" function with the converted file
    #else
    var b:ByteArray = image.encode("png", 1);
    saveText(path, b.toString(), whenDone);
    #end
}

public static function saveText(path:String, content:String, ?whenDone:Bool->Void):Void {
    var success:Bool = true;
    var path2:String = "";
    path = "/assets/data/" + path;
    var a:Array<String> = DataUtils.subfold(path);

    // Flash or HTML5: Not possible to save; error out
    #if (flash || js)
    success = false;
    #if flash
    trace("ERROR: File IO cannot be accessed on Flash.");
    #else
    trace("ERROR: File IO cannot be accessed on HTML5.");
    #end

    // iOS and Android: Attempt to save to the storage directory
    #elseif mobile
    if (!FileSystem.exists(SystemPath.userDirectory + "/" + a[0])) {
        FileSystem.createDirectory(SystemPath.userDirectory + "/" + a[0]);
    }

    path2 = SystemPath.userDirectory + "/" + a[0] + "/" + a[1];
    try {
        File.saveContent(path2, Std.string(content));
    } catch (e:Dynamic) {
        success = false;
        trace("ERROR: " + e);
        errorify(e);
    }

    // Windows, Mac, and Linux: Save straight to the "assets/data/" folder
    #else
    if (!FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.fullPath(a[0]))) {
        FileSystem.createDirectory(FileSystem.fullPath(a[0]));
    }

    path2 = FileSystem.fullPath(a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
    try {
        File.saveContent(path2, Std.string(content));
    } catch (e:Dynamic) {
        success = false;
        trace("ERROR: " + e);
        errorify(e);
    }

    #end
    if (whenDone != null)
        whenDone(success);
}
```

The error is coming from the last `trace("ERROR: " + e);` line. I would troubleshoot myself, but I don't have a Mac or iOS device, and I'm not sure what information I need from the tester.

Bottom line: If there is an apparent error in this code, how can it be fixed? If not, for what troubleshooting information do I need to ask?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something is messing up during Bytes->String conversion which is completely unnecessary here. I suggest you to remove it and use binary version of the FileOutput. If you are using the latest version of lime you can cast your ByteArray to Bytes (since ByteArray underlying type is Bytes) and write that to the FileOutput. Here is how the 'write' part should look like

```
/**
 * Save bytes as a file
 * @param   path    
 * @param   content 
 * @return true if succeed, false overwise
 */
static function saveBytes(path:String, content:Bytes):Bool
{
    var success = false;
    var fo:FileOutput = null;
    try {
        //open binary file and write bytes
        fo = File.write(path, true);    
        fo.writeBytes(content, 0, content.length);          
        success = true;
    } catch (e:Dynamic) {
        trace("ERROR: " + e);
        errorify(e);
    }

    //file output should be closed in any case
    try {
        if (fo != null) 
            fo.close();
    } catch (e:Dynamic) {
        trace("ERROR: " + e);
        errorify(e);
    }

    return success;

}
```

Also, encoding part

```
/* insert your path construction here */
var b:ByteArray = image.encode("png", 1);
var success = saveBytes(path, (b:Bytes));
if (whenDone != null) 
    whenDone(success);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'm having trouble getting this to work; somehow, the same error is now being produced on Windows. Just to be clear, `(b:Bytes)` should be a `haxe.io.Bytes` object, correct?

Comment: To clear things up: variable `b` should be `haxe.io.Bytes`, but since ByteArray is just an abstract of `haxe.io.Bytes` passing it as `(b:Bytes)` is correct. Also, what versions of the libraries and haxe you are using?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I believe I'm using OpenFL 3.3.8, lime 2.6.8, and Haxe 3.2.0.